# Classical Poincare inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$\int_a^b|u(x)|^2dx \le C\int_a^b|u'(x)|^2dx $ for any $u(x)\in C_c^1([a,b])$

The following questions are what I want to know:

1. What does the notation $C_c^1([a,b])$ mean? (little c)
2. condition ' $u(a)=u(b)=0$' is essential to hold poincare inequality? If it is not essential, how can I prove that there is constant c satisfying the inequality?(not necessarily to be best constant)

Comment: $C_c^1$ is the space of compactly supported functions with continuous first derivatives, see more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Functional_analysis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Usually, little $c$ means "compact support". (See the comment of Eff). However, for the Poincare inequality to hold, the assumption $u \in C^1([a,b])$, $u(a)=u(b)=0$ is enough.
2. The condition $u(a)=u(b)=0$ is essential. Otherwise, take $u$ to be a constant function. Then $u' \equiv 0$, but $\int_a^b |u|^2 \, dx > 0$.